# Unable to update array fields in mongoosejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a weird issue I can't resolve. I have a Mongoose schema:

```
Product = new Schema({
  title: {
     type: String
  },
  prices: {
     type: Array
  },
  sync: {
     type: Boolean
  }
  ...
```

I use the post save middleware to update a 3rd party site if the sync flag is true. On return of that operation I update the prices array and set sync to false so that it will not result in an endless loop.

```
Product.post('save', function () { 
    if(this.sync) {
        this.title = "HELLO";
        this.prices[0].retail = '24';
        this.sync = false;
        this.save();
    }
});
```

If I do the above the title and sync fields change but not the prices array. Actually I cannot update any array in my schema. In the above example, the prices array contains about 10 entries - each an object that contains many field including a retail field. I have also tried adding to that array:

```
this.prices.push({ retail: "10 });
```

As well as reinit the array:

```
this.prices = [];
```

No matter what I do it has no effect. Any non array field can however, be updated.

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify what the schema is within an array field (as in `prices`), Mongoose treats it as a `Mixed` field and you have to notify Mongoose of any changes you make to it so that Mongoose knows to save it.  Docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

So your code should change to:

```
Product.post('save', function () { 
    if(this.sync) {
        this.title = "HELLO";
        this.prices[0].retail = '24';
        this.markModified('prices');
        this.sync = false;
        this.save();
    }
});
```